# Geometrically Independent Vectors

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to understand what geometric independence means. Will I be correct to say that a set of vectors is geometrically independent if they cannot all be points enclosed by a regular geometric figure? By regular geometric figure, I mean lines, triangles tetrahedrons, etc.

Comment: yes, for me 3 points in a plane are always geometrically dependent. By "enclosed by a geometric figure", I mean the points lie within or on the boundaries of the figure; the points lie in the interior of the figure or are boundary points.

Comment: Not necessarily. They would have to be such that they cannot be enclosed by any regular geometric figure

Comment: I don't quite understand this

Comment: Geometrically, a (finite) set of vectors is linearly independent iff the dimension of their span equals the numbers of vectors.  As an example, take two parallel vector: we have *two* vectors and the dimension of their span is *one*, hence they are linearly dependent.